# Garbled output on Django development server with Jython

Tags: django, encoding, jython

I'm running Django (1.2.5) on Jython (2.5.2) on Windows 7 (have also tried this on XP with the same results). The problem I'm running into is with the Django development server. The output from the server is garbled in the first few characters of every line.

jython manage.py runserver
Validating models...
0 errors found

Django version 1.2.5, using settings 'Polls.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
←[35;1m[09/Mar/2011 16:33:09] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 64949
←[0m←[32m[09/Mar/2011 16:33:16] "GET /admin HTTP/1.1" 301 0
←[0m←[m[09/Mar/2011 16:33:17] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1882
←[0m

The problem is I can't actually stop the server using Ctrl-C (or Ctrl-Z, etc.). If I try Ctrl-Break, I get what looks to be a very long stack trace, but the server is still running. The only way to stop it, is to close the terminal window entirely.

This only happens when running Django on Jython. On CPython, it's fine.

This also causes problems when entering data like setting the admin super user, etc. The data gets corrupted and is not entered correctly. So it seems to be a character encoding issue. I've googled all over the place and have not been able to find the answer. What am I doing wrong, or what do I need to do? Thanks.

Comment: That's not actually garbled, that's formatting codes that have not been passed through transparently.

Comment: I understand. What can I do to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `DJANGO_COLORS` environment variable to `nocolor` in order to disable Django's attempts to colorize the output.

And then log a bug in the Django bug tracker.

Comment: Ok, that fixed the output formatting codes - thanks. Unfortunately, I still can't stop the server (without closing the terminal window), or enter the super user admin password (it just stays at the "Password:" prompt forever, even if I press <ENTER>. I'll file a bug with Django directly, unless there's a way around this.....

Comment: Hrm. No, that sounds like an interaction issue with Django and Jython directly.